# Is there any alternative to (* keep *) in Verilog using ABC implementation?

Tags: yosys

I am using `yosys` to synthesize using the `synth_ice40` command which calls `ABC` as well. In my Verilog code, I have used `(* keep *) wire wire_1;` `Yosys` does not optimize this but when it comes to `ABC`, it removes these unused wires. Is there anything equivalent to `(* keep *)` which could be used in Verilog which `ABC` does not optimize and remove the certain wires?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Log:
`.44.2. Continuing TECHMAP pass.
No more expansions possible.
Removed 0 unused cells and 3 unused wires.

2.45. Executing OPT_LUT pass (optimize LUTs).
Discovering LUTs.
Number of LUTs:        1
2-LUT                1

Eliminating LUTs.
Number of LUTs:        1
2-LUT                1

Combining LUTs.
Number of LUTs:        1
2-LUT                1

Eliminated 0 LUTs.
Combined 0 LUTs.
<suppressed ~2 debug messages>

2.46. Executing TECHMAP pass (map to technology primitives).

2.46.1. Executing Verilog-2005 frontend: /usr/local/bin/../share/yosys/ice40/cells_map.v
Parsing Verilog input from `/usr/local/bin/../share/yosys/ice40/cells_map.v' to AST representation. Generating RTLIL representation for module` $lut'.
Successfully finished Verilog frontend.

2.46.2. Continuing TECHMAP pass.
Using template $paramod$lut\WIDTH=2\LUT=4'1000 for cells of type $lut.
No more expansions possible.
<suppressed ~14 debug messages>
Removed 0 unused cells and 2 unused wires.`

Comment: Assuming you are using abc within Yosys, keep wires should be preserved so this sounds like a bug.

Comment: Yes, Exactly, I am using abc within Yosys. Yosys preserves the wires, but abc removes. I have added the log above as well.